# serial ctrl+a escape sequence

Tags: python, serial-port, escaping, pyserial

I'm using pyserial to create a serial application. I am looking for the ASCII or ANSI escape sequence for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (go to beginning and end of the line, respectively). I cannot seem to find the escape codes anywhere. Does anyone know of a resource that lists the codes? <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> seem to be pretty universal cursor to beginning of line and cursor to end of line control keys. I have to believe that an escape sequence exists.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `'A'-0x40` a.k.a. `0x01`...

Comment: What kind of serial device are you talking to? What makes you think it support ANSI escapes, or `readline`-style editing, or whatever? Or are you trying to edit user input before sending it to the serial device or something?

Answer (score 3):

Neither ASCII characters nor ANSI control codes really quite define a thing called <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

However, the ASCII control characters 0-31 (which officially have names from NUL through US) are traditionally mapped as the "control version" of the printable characters 64-95. So, 0 is ^@, 1 is ^A, 2 is ^B, etc.

The Wikipedia pages on [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) and [control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) give further information.

So, ^A is 1, and ^E is 5.

---

Meanwhile:

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> seem to be pretty universal cursor to beginning of line and cursor to end of line control keys.

They're not that universal. These are part of the "basic emacs control keys", which a number of Unix terminal emulators and some Unix-based GUI apps (and things like the `libreadline` CLI editing library and the `Qt` text widgets) support by convention. However, try hitting ^A in, say, a DOS prompt or Microsoft Word and it won't go to the start of the line.

And, just sending ^A or ^E to an ANSI-compatible terminal won't necessarily move the cursor to the start or end of the line. To do that properly, you want to actually send the corresponding ANSI control sequences. Any list of ANSI escape codes, like [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences), will show you what's available.

Unfortunately, there *is* no right answer to what you're trying to do. ANSI treats the entire 80x25 (or whatever) screen as accessible, and doesn't distinguish between character positions that have something in them and those that are blank. So, you can't move to the "end of the line", unless by that you mean "column 79".

And, if what you're looking for is moving to columns 0 and 79, that's easy with the `CHA` command (`'\x1b[0G'` and `'\x1b[79G'`)—but not all ANSI terminals support that; in particular, DOS ANSI.SYS and anything built to be compatible with it will ignore it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. CTRL+A is \x01, CTRL+E is \x05. I found a fairly comprehensive list from a link at the bottom of the Wikipedia page. For convenience, here is the [link](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3320804: That resource has a pretty weird subset of the ANSI commands. It's sort of close to the subset that are common to ANSI.SYS, VT100, and xterm-color… but not quite even that. I guess if you don't use colors, and don't use any of the features that are different in ANSI.SYS (like moving left from column 0), they're the features that are about as safe and portable as possible?